# SQL Injection Threat?

Tags: sql, scala, sql-injection

Is the code below subject to SQL Injection and if so, any recommendations on fixing it. Thanks

```
def Function(x: Int, y: Int) = {
  var query = s"SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $x, $y"
}
```

Comment: Does Scala have a PreparedStatement you can use?

Comment: you can always use the java api from scala, so yes actually PreparedStatement can be used

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
On reflection, I just realized that because this is a `LIMIT` field, and because `Int.MAX_INT` is so high, I would see this as a potential security concern, though probably not SQL Injection exactly. This is because the caller, if the input data is coming from an untrusted source, would be able to potentially cause the database to do far more work than expected.

The values being passed to `LIMIT` should be validated to be within expected reasonable ranges, and I would also consider using `PreparedStatement`.

Because the types passed to the function are of type `Int`, the type safety of Scala's type system means that these are guaranteed to be Integer values. As such, arbitrary SQL cannot be injected into the SQL and so I would not see this as being subject to SQL Injection as such.

However, using a `PreparedStatement` with parameter markers is better for other reasons besides security also, e.g. performance, so switching to use a `PreparedStatement`, or other SQL library with features that abstract over `PreparedStatement`s would be useful here.

Note that the Java JDBC API, which includes `PreparedStatement` is available in Scala, so could be used, and there are numerous Scala specific libraries which can be used, which abstract over the raw JDBC APIs.